# Why boost::interprocess::managed_shared_ptr to non-const can not be converted to managed_shared_ptr to const

Tags: c++, boost, interprocess

As I understand the following is valid for boost::shared_ptr:

```
boost::shared_ptr<SomeData> ptr;
...
boost::shared_ptr<const SomeData> c_ptr = ptr; // Valid
```

The same behavior does not hold for `boost::interprocess::managed_shared_ptr`. Why?

Answer (score 1):

`boost::interprocess::managed_shared_ptr` isn't actually a shared pointer; it's just a helper class that you can use to define the type of one. From the [interprocess docs](http://ci.boost.org/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=repos+1&path=%2Fbranches%2Frelease%2Flibs%2Finterprocess%2Fdoc%2Finterprocess.qbk&rev=82250&peg=82250):

> `typedef managed_shared_ptr<MyType, managed_shared_memory>::type my_shared_ptr;`
>
> And the creation of a shared pointer can be simplified to this:
>
> [c++]
>
> `my_shared_ptr sh_ptr = make_managed_shared_ptr
>         (segment.construct<MyType>("object to share")(), segment);`

With "`sh_ptr`" from the above example, the following should work:

```
typedef managed_shared_ptr<const MyType, managed_shared_memory>::type my_shared_const_ptr;
my_shared_const_ptr sh_c_ptr = sh_ptr;
```

As these two objects are actually shared pointers.

On the other hand, doing:

```
managed_shared_ptr<MyType, managed_shared_memory> ptr;
managed_shared_ptr<const MyType, managed_shared_memory> c_ptr = ptr;
```

won't work because in this case ptr and c_ptr are [very simple structs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/managed_shared_ptr.html) that do nothing except make 3 typedefs, so they don't convert.